# TYPO3 9.5 LTS route enhancer with f:select

Tags: typo3-9.x

I'm using a simple extension, which displays a list of properties from a domainobject in a f:select. After using the dropdown the form redirects to an controller action and the repository gets all records according to the choosen property by argument.

```
<f:form class="filter-select" name="filter-select" method="post" action="showByProperty" pageUid="{settings.detailShowByProperty}">
<f:form.select name="filter-form" options="{properties}" optionLabelField="title" optionValueField="uid" prependOptionLabel="Please choose..." prependOptionValue="0"  />
    <button>
        Show matching records
    </button>
```

How can i use route enhancers with select field to create an url like:

```
http:www.mysite.com/detailpage/property
```

Especially i dont know how to append the property / argument.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This wont't work. Sending an form is completly handled by client / browser. Only option is to send the form to another action which creates an redirect with uriBuilder and form data as parameters to get an speaking url.